# Using old pc keyboard key-mapings on MAC oS

Tags: macos, ubuntu

All in all "I want my ubuntu shortcuts on MAC OS X"

I am on mac os for the first time and I really miss my old keyboard.
So I decided to get the old pc keyboard and use it instead of MAC OS keyboard.

The first step was to change the key mappings
https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqvE0.png

No problem here, but the problem arises when for example I want to override <kbd>COMAND</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> to use <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>TAB</kbd> instead.

Is there any good tutorial for this kind of things ?

Next thing I hate a lot is my page up , page down, home and end button does not work properly.

Next how do you do fast movement in text ?
For example in ubuntu you can press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>LEFT/RIGHT</kbd> and you can jump between words very fast...

Next when I press the end button I want to go to the end of line not to end of document, <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>END</kbd> should go to end of document...

and so on and so on...

Does anybody else straggle with these things ?
Does anybody have an solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

I use Karabiner for keymapping on OSX, works like a charm:
https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/

Comment: Is it safe to use third party software ? I mean is it checked if it sends some key(typing) log to some server ?